# Разбить pre на строки

Tags: php

В теге `<pre>` лежит текст:

```
npc_create npc_barnacle          - создать Barnacle
npc_create npc_combine_s         - создать Combine
npc_create npc_alyx              - создать Alyx
```

Как разбить его на строки?

Пробовал так, но не получается:

```
print_r(explode('\n', $pre));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print_r(explode(PHP_EOL, $pre));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
explode('<br />', nl2br($pre));
```

Answer (score 2):

Специальный символ: `\n` (новая строка) работает только в двойных кавычках.